# Size of a char in C

Tags: c, char, sizeof

**I have:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch[] = "Hello";
    char wd[] = "World";
    char ex[] = "!";

    printf("The size of a char: %ld\n",sizeof(char));
    printf("The size of ch[]: %ld\n",sizeof(ch));
    printf("The size of ex[]: %ld\n",sizeof(ex));
    printf("The size of wd[]: %ld\n",sizeof(wd));

    return 0;
}
```

**Which yields:**

```
The size of a char: 1
The size of ch[]: 6
The size of ex[]: 2
The size of wd[]: 6
```

**My question:** Since the size of a char is 1 byte,why isn't the size of ch[ ]=5 bytes? Since it has 5 characters *(H,e,l,l and o)*
The same goes with wd[ ] and ex[ ]. What's going on here?
Sorry if this is a no-brainer,but I am novice in C.

Comment: If you want to get the length of the char[](result 5), use strlen(ch).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this statement:

```
char ch[] = "Hello";
```

A null terminated string literal is copied into `ch`. Therefore there are six characters, including the NUL terminator. Note that `strlen` will **not** count the NUL terminator.

```
char c[] = "Hello";
printf("%s", c);
```

Therefore, you should use `strlen` when you want the size of the string, and `sizeof` when you want the amount of bytes in the string. Note that in the case you have a character pointer, and not an array, it will have no size information.

```
char* ptr = "Hello";
sizeof(ptr); // size of a character pointer
sizeof(*ptr); // size of a char
strlen(ptr);
```

Comment: You should not use `sizeof` when you want to get amount of bytes in a string. `sizeof` should only be used on arrays. A string is not always an array, it might be a pointer.

Comment: @self  A _string_ in C is not a pointer.  "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character". §7.1.1 1

Comment: @chix Obviously. Read as: *A variable holding the string...*

Comment: @self Responding to your comment "A string is not always an array, it might be a pointer."

Comment: @chux I think it is pretty obvious what I meant. Sometimes it is best to not interpret every sentence literally.

Comment: @self I thought the comment meant what was written and not some other implied meaning.  The assertion "A string ... might be a pointer" was incorrect and I provided a reference explaining why I thought so.  No malice intended, no hidden agenda.

Comment: And c++ syntax in c post?

Answer (score 7):

Since C strings are terminated with a `\0`, the size of the string will always be the (apparent) length + 1.

Answer (score 4):

C strings are null terminated.  That is, there is an extra zero byte at the end of each of your strings.

For what it's worth, `sizeof(char)` is *always* `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Strings in C always have at least one character: '\0'. This character is at the end of every proper string, so while the string length may be 5 bytes in size, it actually requires 6 bytes to store the string fully.

Just try this:

```
char empty[] = "";
printf("size: %zu\n", sizeof empty);
printf("empty[0]: %hhd\n", empty[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimum size of a char array would be 1 byte which would be empty i.e. contain only `\0` 1 null byte. c strings i.e char arrays always end in `\0` (null byte) so a char array with 5 letters would be 5 letters plus the null byte equals 6 bytes.
One could initialize a char array with 5 bytes which would only fit 4 letters plus the null byte.

`char ch[5];`

`ch is 5 bytes`

Reference:
https://devdocs.io/c/string/byte

Comment: So what would `char string[5] = "string";` result in?